# Java script on focus instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, onfocus

How to change and use this function:

```
$(function() {
  $("a#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#yellow_div").slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

to run when **input text** get focus?

```
<input id="toggle" type="text" />
   <div id="yellow_div" style="display:none;">
      <p>Hello</p> 
   </div>
```

Comment: Did you rtfm? This very much looks like "give me teh codez!".

Comment: So bind to the focus event....

Answer (score 0):

This will run the code when your input gets focused

```
$(function () {
   $("#toggle").focus(function () {
      $("#yellow_div").slideToggle();
      return false;
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#toggle").focus(function() {
```

or

```
$("#toggle").on('focus', function() {
```

Should do the trick, as long as you're talking about your `input#toggle`